How to add space for a 1/0 neutral wire in service neutral bar
I've got an old Crouse-Hinds 200a panel that I'm tying a 150a subpanel for a basement into using 1/0 wire. Unfortunately my service neutral bar is super crowded. I was able to move some things around and make space near the larger size hole for the 1/0 neutral but it doesn't seem big enough. It's too tight to get a caliper back there but you can see loosely how big it is.
What are my options here? Finding parts compatible with this panel has been tough in general.
Yes, I need to upgrade my whole panel, but that's a next year project, not something I can afford to tackle right now.





Try an ECLK2SC
According to an older Murray catalog I dug up, the "Swiss Cheese" type of neutral and grounding bars that have been a feature of Murray panels since well before yours was made accept the ECLK2SC lug kit.  While not listed in the current Siemens catalogs, it appears that some distributor stock of the part is still available; you may need to go to a local supplyhouse to find it though.
